# MySQL error on SET

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

Every time I try to run this query, I get a MySQL error near

```
'BEGIN SET @v1 = 60000' at line 3
```

I have no clue what I am doing wrong, I appreciate the help!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertgear

BEGIN
   SET @v1 = 60000;
   WHILE v1 < 61000 DO
     <insert statement>
     SET v1 = v1 + 1
   END WHILE;
END

CALL insertgear
```

*EDIT The reason I start at 60000 is because I use that number in my insert as an ID

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `v1` and tidy up your syntax a bit, e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertgear()

BEGIN
    DECLARE v1 int;
    SET v1 = 60000;
    WHILE v1 < 61000 DO
        <insert statement>
        SET v1 = v1 + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

Comment: Thanks, added those changes but still get an error `BEGIN DECLARE @v1 int at line 3`

Comment: The @ prefix is used for session variables in mysql, I've amended the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Need to declare first, and I'd use := since = is evaluated as a comparison operator in a query. Not that set v1 = 6000 is a query, but for consistency. This seems to work in sqlfiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7be13/1

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertgear()
BEGIN
    DECLARE v1 int DEFAULT 1;
    SET v1 := 60000;

    WHILE v1 < 61000 DO
        <insert stm>
        SET v1 := v1 + 1;
    END WHILE;

END
//

call insertgear();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I get the same error that I posted @TobyLL comment

Comment: Do you still get it now? It seems to work in sqfiddle.